# Html5 video repeats in safari while buffering

Tags: php, html, video, safari, buffering

I am playing a video with the HTML5 `<video>` element. Everything works fine but while the video is streaming, the part of video which is already loaded is repeatedly played in Safari. How do  I stop playing the video repeatedly?

Here is the [link](http://dev.youcustomize.com/public/upload/926751132267026946930.mp4) to the video.

Comment: Was unable to replicate it on my Safari 5.1.1 in Lion.

Comment: Replicated on my windows machine. On event "waiting" I output the loop property and I get false. I perform a pause on "waiting" and video pauses but the currentTime jumps to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this problem on windows. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the loop function being activated and it might be a bug under safari. Please provide the html page with the video integrated so we can see it in action in your website.